# CSS div background image help

Tags: css, html

I want to have a CSS div that has a background image (the full image size is 950px x 306px), that shows the entire background image, and that adjusts the sizing of the background image depending on the browser size.

So the CSS div code should:

- Have a background image of some picture with a max width of 950px and max height 306px
- Show that entire background image (adjust the image size to fill the entire div)
- Resize itself automatically depending on size of the the enclosing div / browser width (some definition like width="100%")

Can someone please help with this? I'm really new to CSS and have been trying many different methods but none seem to work. I really appreciate your help!

P.S. No JQuery please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body
{
background-image:url('image.gif');
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: Works, thank you.. I will accept the answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to resize for the user's browser, it'll have to be dynamic. You cannot do that with CSS alone. 
This may be of use: http://imageresizing.net/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
body{margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    overflow:hidden;
}

img#background{position:absolute; 
    z-index:1; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    top:0; 
    left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/nTLXA/1/

Then position `div`s on top of this.